# spring ws use request certificate to encrypt response

Tags: java, spring-ws

I am looking for an equivalent to Apache CXFs configuration value ["useReqSigCert"](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/apidocs/org/apache/wss4j/common/ConfigurationConstants.html#USE_REQ_SIG_CERT).

With this configuration the public key to encrypt the response is taken from the request (transmitted in a BinarySecurityToken).

Is there an option with Spring WS?

In a broader sense, I am looking for a way to extract the BinarySecurityToken (X509Certificate) from a SOAP-Request (WS-Security enabled, encryption of SoapBody and signed) and then encrypt the SOAP-Response (SoapBody) with this certificate.

Comment: Under the hood Spring ws use wss4j as well. I don't know if it will work, but you can try setting the configuration property [`securementEncryptionUser`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/fa76440fd813f05d2aa732d52a92395d48e36ee2/spring-ws-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/wss4j2/Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java#L293-L312) to `useReqSigCert` when [configuring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/#_encryption_2) your response `encryption`. I hope it helps.

Comment: @jccampanero Very good hint. This seems to work, if you add it as an anwer you can get the bounty.

Comment: Thank you very much  @beat. I am very happy to hear that it worked properly. Thank you very much, I wrote an answer with the indicated information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transforming a comment in an answer, under the hood, Spring web services can use `wss4j` like Apache CXF.

Please, try setting the configuration property [`securementEncryptionUser`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/fa76440fd813f05d2aa732d52a92395d48e36ee2/spring-ws-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/wss4j2/Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java#L293-L312) to `useReqSigCert` when configuring your response encryption. Please, consider read the [relevant documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/#_encryption_2).